# Able to connect to MySQL from EC2, but not node-mysql for some reason

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to MySQL from the command line and it works just fine. In code, when I do it, I get `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`. My MySQL box is on an EC2 (ports are open and bind-address is commented out). My Node server is on an EC2 (a separate one), with only port 22 open.

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong port was my problem. Fixed.